# Looking for an old anime or cartoon show of a family who can transform into green monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

There was an anime about this family of three who could transform into green monsters. The dad wore a hat, the mom wore a dress and the son wore some sort of onesie because it was the same colour. It was an old anime but I don't remember the name anymore. Please help me find it.

Comment: Can you remember anything more about the characters or what style it was in?

Answer (score 10):

I'm quite sure this is [*"Humanoid Monster Bem"* (*Yōkai Ningen Bemu*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanoid_Monster_Bem).

The protagonists are *Bem*, *Bela* and *Belo* (the last ones named *Bera* and *Bero* in some languages), three mysterious creatures usually having a human-like appearance but capable of switching to a more monstrous form.
They help humanity against evil men and monsters, but due to their frightening appearance they are ofter discriminated and have to fly and hide from the same people they just saved.

[image: cover image for an Italian dvd]

Their outfit matches perfectly your description, and the youngest character, in his monster form, is definitely green.

The original series, which the image above refers to, aired in Japan in 1968 and in the following years in many other countries; a second one with an almost identical character design aired in 2006; finally, cited just for completeness sake, a third one aired in 2019 (this one having a completely different visual style, and of course it cannot be defined "old").

Images from the second series, with the characters in their humanoid form and monster form:

[image: Bem 2007, humanoid form]

[image: Bem 2007, monster form]

Comment: Impressive! Was this one you were familiar with? If not, how did you search for it?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I watched a rerun of the original series in 2002; even if I cannot now remember the details of a single episode, the general look and tone is memorable and I was immediately reminded of it when I read the question.