# Cartoon series about a monster family that solves mysteries

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

Watched it back in the mid to late 90s. Probably made 80s-90s ish.

Pretty sure all the main characters were monsters of some kind? There was an adult male and adult female monster along with a young boy monster.

I remember one episode where they look into realistic statues of people that you can hear crying, and when they break a piece off they find human hair.  Turns out the statue maker was casting real people into statues.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PhCrCHHuSQ - Monster High?

Comment: "Humanoid Monster Bem"? In that case, it would be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/229756/40711

Comment: @Ifurini - Humanoid Monster Bem is what I was remembering.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could be [*"Humanoid Monster Bem" (Yōkai Ningen Bemu)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanoid_Monster_Bem), an anime first aired in 1968.

The main characters are three mysterious creatures, named Bem, Bera and Bero, respectively looking as a dark-skinned tall man with a black coat and hat and a white cane, a pale woman wearing a purple dress and a green/red cape, and a kid dressed in red.
In this form they appear mostly human (despite having only three-fingered hands) and interact with other people, but they can switch to a more monstrous form.

Here are the characters in their humanoid and monstrous forms (these images are from the 2007 remake series, but the design is quite the same as in the original one):

[image: Bem 2007, humanoid form]

[image: Bem 2007, monster form]

Their origins are only hinted at. An introduction repeated at the beginning of each episode after the opening song states that *"no one really knows when they were born; in a dark and silent place a cell multiplied, giving origin to three living beings, different from humans and from any other life form on Earth; behind their hideous appearance, they have a deep sense of justice"*.

Each episode tipically has them arriving in a new location and investigating the sinister events happening there, involving either supernatural monsters or cruel criminals.

---

The specific episode you remember should be episode #18 *"The mysterious sculptor"*.
A mad artist creates his statues by capturing people and encasing them in bronze or plaster. After discovering the corpse inside one of these statues, Bero and the other monsters try to stop him.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it's probably [*Gargoyles*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108783/) (1994 - 1996).

> A clan of heroic night creatures pledge to protect modern New York City as they did in Scotland one thousand years earlier.

You can watch the trailer here:

It is also available to watch on Disney+. Presumably the episode you remember is one of the "City Of Stone" episodes from Season 2 Episodes 9 - 12. Episode synopses taken from Dinsey+:

> P1: Demona casts a spell turning every human in Manhattan into stone.
> P2: Xanatos and Goliath team up to stop Demona from destroying human "statues".
> P3: Xanatos, the Steel Clan and the gargoyles prepare to break Demona's spell.
> P4: Macbeth and Demona battle. Demona's spell is finally broken.

---

I found this by Googling `90s cartoon monster family solves crimes` which turned up [this "Top 35 Most Nostalgic TV Cartoons Of My Childhood" page](https://rateyourmusic.com/list/jweber14/top_35_most_nostalgic_tv_cartoons_of_my_childhood/) where *Gargoyles* is 21 in the list.